# How up-to-date is the Github BigQuery dataset really?

Tags: google-bigquery

The official [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github) says the update frequency is weekly, but what exactly does that mean? Because when I query the dataset for my own github repos, then only repos I created/updated before ~august 2015 show up. Everything newer is nowhere to be found.

Do I need a paid plan to get access to the latest data? What am I doing wrong?

For reference, this is the simple query I ran to get all files that contain my Github username:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.files]
WHERE
  repo_name CONTAINS 'my_github_name'
```

Comment: Can you mention a specific repository so we can debug?

Comment: Yeah sure, I thought this was a general problem/limitation so I omitted my username. When I run the above query with my Github username `simonvizzini` then I get only files for the repos `simonvizzini/refluxjs` and `simonvizzini/superagent`, but my other repos don't show up.

Comment: for specifics - https://github.com/simonvizzini/riotjs-dbmonster doesn't have a LICENSE - the dataset won't ingest anything that can't be determined to be open source

Comment: Ah, thanks! That makes sense. I'm sure this info is somewhere in the docs but I couldn't see it. And do you maybe know why my only other non-fork repo - https://github.com/simonvizzini/vscode-factorio-lua-api-autocomplete, which is now over a month old, doesn't show up in the dataset? The update interval seems to be longer than weekly. But that wouldn't matter for my use case anyway, as long as every github repo is eventually indexed.

Comment: License looks good here! And yes, it might take some time for the pipeline to find about new projects - otherwise it updates weekly.